# printing with format is printing quotation marks?

Tags: f#

When I run `printfn "hello"`, the outcome is `hello` (without quotation marks). However, when I run

```
let mystring = "hello"
printfn "%A" mystring
```

the outcome is `"hello"` (with quotation marks). Why is this and how can I then print with a format/parameter without having quotation marks appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printfn "%s" "hello"
```

Here is the 
[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.printf-module-%5Bfsharp%5D)
and another helpful
[link](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/)